# Expand Text Widget without expanding other widgets tkinter

Tags: python, tkinter, widget

I'm trying to make a layout with only STD'S Frames resizable. I tried using `row_configure` and `column_configure`, but due to the fact that widgets are on frames, or the fact that frames have `columnspan`, widgets don't seem to resize. 
Here is how the layout looks like now.

[image: Sample Layout]

Any suggestions?

**`'text.txt`' REQUIRED FOR CODE**

```
R1:Saluda y pregunta al inicio los roles y nombres, y si desea cargar una partida.:Errores importantes son, por ejemplo, no preguntar directamente por los roles.
R2:Dialogo con el usuario durante el transcurso de un turno: durante cada turno pregunta la jugada del usuario y si desea guardar la partida, además explica de forma adecuada el formato del movimiento.:Muestra claramente cómo debe ser el input para el movimiento. Lo demás es meramente el acto de preguntar. Preguntar por guardar es un punto, mientras que "preguntar y explicar bien el movimiento" también es un punto.
R3:Al final de una partida avisa el ganador y pregunta si quiere seguir jugando. En caso de que no quieran seguir, entonces termina el juego. De lo contrario, se reinicia el juego de 0.:El programa debe manejar que el usuario no quiere seguir jugando, es decir, que si el jugador elige no seguir el juego termina de forma correcta sin caerse. Entiendase "reiniciar de cero" que es como si el programa corriese por primera vez. 
R4:Imprime el tablero 5x5 con las fichas representadas según formato.:Es importante que concuerde con el sistema de coordenadas descrito en el enunciado y el formato de este.
R5:Recibe y decodifica el input del movimiento de forma correcta:Pide el input en el formato pedido en el enunciado y lo guarda y/o utiliza.
R6:Efectúa el movimiento indicado de forma correcta (siempre que este sea válido).:Esta parte se debe corregir solamente con movimientos válidos. El movimiento de comer una gallina no cuenta aquí ya que este se evalúa en R8 y R9.
R7:Avisa cuando una jugada es inválida, además de evitar dicha jugada. (No es necesario controlar coordenadas fuera de rango):La mayoría de los errores posibles son importantes, por lo que se puede omitir el nivel Aceptable (2) de logro. En caso de jugadas inválidas el programa debe evitar hacerla, de lo contrario esto se considera como error importante.
R8:Lleva a cabo el movimiento de comer una gallina.:Solamente Completo o No logrado. 
R9:Lleva a cabo el movimiento de comer a más de una gallina en un solo turno.:El mayor caso es de 3 gallinas de una sola vez, lo cual pueden probar con el archivo de prueba correspondiente. También hay que tomar en cuenta que en este caso es obligación que el coyote coma una gallina, por lo tanto si el programa permite mover hacia otro lado cuenta como error importante.
R10:Detecta cuando ganan las gallinas.:Solamente es No logrado o Completo.
R11:Detecta cuando gana el coyote.:Solamente es No logrado o Completo.
R12:Guarda la partida en el formato correcto.:La mayoría de los errores posibles son importantes, por lo que se puede omitir el nivel Aceptable (2) de logro. 
R13:Carga correctamente la partida y muestra el historial de jugadas.:Con tal de que cada jugada se pueda ver claramente, la parte del historial esta correcto. Al momento de corregir  se debe utilizar un archivo que este en el formato correcto.
R14:Luego de cargar una partida se puede seguir jugando sobre esta.
R15:Formato de entrega:Archivo mal subido, archivo .py no corresponde a las instrucciones.
```

**CODE**

```
import tkinter as tk
import tkinter.font as tkfont
from tkinter import ttk
import os
import subprocess
import glob

# GLOBALY USED

previous_value = []


def update_all(event):
    with open('saved_data.txt', 'r') as notas:
        for linea in notas:
            nro_alumno = linea.split(',')[0]
            if nro_alumno == nro_alumnos.get():
                stdin_filename.set(files[alumnos.index(nro_alumno)])
                obtained = linea.strip().split(',')[1:]
                for entrada, dato in zip(entradas.keys(), obtained):
                    entradas[entrada][0].delete(0, tk.END)
                    entradas[entrada][0].insert(0, int(dato))
                update_scores()


def clear(event):
    previous_value.append([event.widget, event.widget.get()])
    event.widget.delete(0, tk.END)


def move_down(event):
    for entrada in entradas:
        if entradas[entrada][0] == root.focus_get():
            index = int(entrada[1:])
            if index == 15:
                index = 1
            else:
                index += 1
            new_focus = f'R{index}'
            entradas[new_focus][0].focus_set()
            return


def move_up(event):
    for entrada in entradas:
        if entradas[entrada][0] == root.focus_get():
            index = int(entrada[1:])
            if index == 1:
                index = 15
            else:
                index -= 1
            new_focus = f'R{index}'
            entradas[new_focus][0].focus_set()
            return


def update_puntajes():
    alumno = nro_alumnos.get()
    with open('saved_data.txt', 'r') as archivo:
        datos = archivo.read().splitlines()
    puntajes = []
    for entrada in entradas.keys():
        puntajes.append(str(entradas[entrada][0].get()))
    for dato in datos:
        if dato.split(',')[0] == alumno:
            datos[datos.index(dato)] = ','.join([dato.split(',')[0]] + puntajes)
    with open('saved_data.txt', 'w') as archivo:
        for dato in datos:
            if dato == datos[-1]:
                archivo.write(dato)
            else:
                archivo.write(dato + '\n')
    with open('puntajes.csv', 'r') as archivo:
        datos = archivo.read().splitlines()
    puntajes = []
    for entrada in entradas.keys():
        puntajes.append(str(entradas[entrada][2].get()))
    for dato in datos:
        if dato.split(';')[0] == alumno:
            datos[datos.index(dato)] = ';'.join([dato.split(';')[0]] + puntajes)
    with open('puntajes.csv', 'w') as archivo:
        for dato in datos:
            if dato == datos[-1]:
                archivo.write(dato)
            else:
                archivo.write(dato + '\n')


def update_scores(event=None):
    try:
        previous_widget = previous_value.pop(0)
        if previous_widget[0].get() == '':
            previous_widget[0].insert(0, previous_widget[1])
    except IndexError:
        pass

    maximos = {
        'R1': 1,
        'R2': 2,
        'R3': 2,
        'R4': 4,
        'R5': 2,
        'R6': 4,
        'R7': 5,
        'R8': 4,
        'R9': 8,
        'R10': 6,
        'R11': 4,
        'R12': 5,
        'R13': 8,
        'R14': 5,
        'R15': 1
    }
    for entrada in entradas.keys():
        entradas[entrada][1].delete(0, tk.END)
        try:
            entradas[entrada][2].set((int(entradas[entrada][0].get()) * maximos[entrada]) / 3)
        except ValueError:
            pass


root = tk.Tk()


def bold(size=None):
    if not size:
        return tkfont.Font(weight='bold')
    else:
        return tkfont.Font(size=size, weight='bold')


def sized(size):
        return tkfont.Font(size=size)


def refresh_rubrica(event):
    current = rubrica_dropdown.get()
    for value in rubric_values:
        if value[0] == current:
            descripcion_var.set(value[1])
            comentarios_var.set(value[2])


def create_data_files():
    if os.path.isfile(os.getcwd()+os.sep+'saved_data.txt') and os.path.isfile(os.getcwd()+os.sep+'puntajes.csv'):
        return
    with open('saved_data.txt', 'w') as archivo:
        archivo.write('Nro,R1,R2,R3,R4,R5,R6,R7,R8,R9,R10,R11,R12,R13,R14,R15\n')
        for alumno in alumnos:
            if alumno != alumnos[-1]:
                archivo.write(alumno + ',0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0\n')
            else:
                archivo.write(alumno + ',0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0')

    with open('puntajes.csv', 'w') as archivo:
        archivo.write('Nro;R1;R2;R3;R4;R5;R6;R7;R8;R9;R10;R11;R12;R13;R14;R15\n')
        for alumno in alumnos:
            if alumno != alumnos[-1]:
                archivo.write(alumno + ';0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0\n')
            else:
                archivo.write(alumno + ';0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0')


def process():
    if len(ID_entry.get())==0:
        ERROR_VAR.set('DEBES INGRESAR ALGO!')
        return
    try:
        os.chdir(os.getcwd() + os.sep + ID_entry.get())
        for file in os.listdir(os.getcwd()):
            if file not in ['puntajes.csv', 'saved_data.txt', 'input.txt', 'out.txt', 'err.txt']:
                alumnos.append(file.split('_')[0])
                files.append('_'.join(list(map(lambda x: x.lower(), file.split('_')[1:]))))
        create_data_files()
        nro_alumnos['values'] = alumnos
    except FileNotFoundError:
        ERROR_VAR.set('ESE ID NO EXISTE!')
        return
    else:
        ERROR_VAR.set('')
    create_data_files()
    config.destroy()
    root.deiconify()


def run():
    print(stdin_text.get(tk.END))
    inp_file = open('input.txt', 'w')
    inp_file.write(stdin_text.get('1.0', tk.END))
    inp_file.close()
    infile = open('input.txt', 'r')
    outfile = open('out.txt', 'w')
    errfile = open('err.txt', 'w')
    subprocess.run('python '+ glob.glob(nro_alumnos.get() + '*')[0], stdin=infile, stdout=outfile, stderr=errfile)
    infile.close()
    outfile.close()
    errfile.close()
    stdout_text.configure(state='normal')
    stdout_text.delete('1.0', tk.END)
    with open('out.txt', 'r') as file:
        stdout_text.insert('1.0', file.read())
    stdout_text.configure(state='disabled')
    stderr_text.configure(state='normal')
    stderr_text.delete('1.0', tk.END)
    with open('err.txt', 'r') as file:
        stderr_text.insert('1.0', file.read())
    stderr_text.configure(state='disabled')
    os.remove('input.txt')
    os.remove('out.txt')
    os.remove('err.txt')
# GLOBALS CONFIG

files = []
alumnos = []
entry_frame = tk.Frame(root)
entradas = {
    'R1': [tk.Entry(entry_frame), tk.Entry(entry_frame), tk.DoubleVar(entry_frame, value=0.0)],
    'R2': [tk.Entry(entry_frame), tk.Entry(entry_frame), tk.DoubleVar(entry_frame, value=0.0)],
    'R3': [tk.Entry(entry_frame), tk.Entry(entry_frame), tk.DoubleVar(entry_frame, value=0.0)],
    'R4': [tk.Entry(entry_frame), tk.Entry(entry_frame), tk.DoubleVar(entry_frame, value=0.0)],
    'R5': [tk.Entry(entry_frame), tk.Entry(entry_frame), tk.DoubleVar(entry_frame, value=0.0)],
    'R6': [tk.Entry(entry_frame), tk.Entry(entry_frame), tk.DoubleVar(entry_frame, value=0.0)],
    'R7': [tk.Entry(entry_frame), tk.Entry(entry_frame), tk.DoubleVar(entry_frame, value=0.0)],
    'R8': [tk.Entry(entry_frame), tk.Entry(entry_frame), tk.DoubleVar(entry_frame, value=0.0)],
    'R9': [tk.Entry(entry_frame), tk.Entry(entry_frame), tk.DoubleVar(entry_frame, value=0.0)],
    'R10': [tk.Entry(entry_frame), tk.Entry(entry_frame), tk.DoubleVar(entry_frame, value=0.0)],
    'R11': [tk.Entry(entry_frame), tk.Entry(entry_frame), tk.DoubleVar(entry_frame, value=0.0)],
    'R12': [tk.Entry(entry_frame), tk.Entry(entry_frame), tk.DoubleVar(entry_frame, value=0.0)],
    'R13': [tk.Entry(entry_frame), tk.Entry(entry_frame), tk.DoubleVar(entry_frame, value=0.0)],
    'R14': [tk.Entry(entry_frame), tk.Entry(entry_frame), tk.DoubleVar(entry_frame, value=0.0)],
    'R15': [tk.Entry(entry_frame), tk.Entry(entry_frame), tk.DoubleVar(entry_frame, value=0.0)]
}
# ENTRY CONFIG
for entry in entradas.keys():
    entradas[entry][0].configure(width=5)
    entradas[entry][0].bind('<FocusOut>', update_scores)
    entradas[entry][0].bind('<FocusIn>', clear)
    entradas[entry][0].bind('<Down>', move_down)
    entradas[entry][0].bind('<Up>', move_up)
    entradas[entry][1].configure(width=5)
    entradas[entry][1].configure(width=5, state='readonly', textvariable=entradas[entry][2])

# ENTRY GRIDDING
for i, entry in enumerate(entradas.keys(), 3):
    label = tk.Label(entry_frame, text=entry, justify='center')
    label.grid(column=0, row=i, pady=2, padx=2)
    entradas[entry][0].grid(column=1, row=i, pady=2, padx=2, sticky=tk.W)
    entradas[entry][1].grid(column=2, row=i, pady=2, padx=2, sticky=tk.W)

# NRO ALUMNOS

nro_label = tk.Label(entry_frame, text='Puntaje', font=bold())  # TITLE
column_labelN = tk.Label(entry_frame, text='Nivel')
column_labelN.grid(column=1, row=2)
column_labelP = tk.Label(entry_frame, text='Puntaje')
column_labelP.grid(column=2, row=2)
nro_label.grid(column=0, row=0, sticky='nw')
nro_alumnos = ttk.Combobox(entry_frame, width=10, state='readonly')
nro_alumnos.bind('<<ComboboxSelected>>', update_all)
nro_alumnos['values'] = alumnos
nro_alumnos_label = tk.Label(entry_frame, text='N°de alumno')
nro_alumnos_label.grid(column=0, row=1, sticky='nw')
nro_alumnos.grid(column=1, row=1, columnspan=2, sticky='nw')
entry_frame.grid(column=0, row=0, columnspan=3, rowspan=15, sticky='n')
# RUBRICA
rubric_values = []
with open('text.txt', 'r') as a:
    rubric_data = a.read().splitlines()
for R in rubric_data:
    rubric_values.append(R.split(':'))
frame_rubrica = tk.Frame(root, width=100, height=100)
label_descRub = tk.Label(frame_rubrica, text='Descripcion: ', font=bold(7))
label_comRub = tk.Label(frame_rubrica, text='Comentarios: ', font=bold(7))
descripcion_var = tk.StringVar(frame_rubrica, value='None')
descripcion_rubrica = tk.Label(frame_rubrica, textvariable=descripcion_var, wraplength=200,
                               justify='left', font=sized(7))
comentarios_var = tk.StringVar(frame_rubrica, value='None')
comentarios_rubrica = tk.Label(frame_rubrica, textvariable=comentarios_var, wraplength=200,
                               justify='left', font=sized(7))
r_label = tk.Label(frame_rubrica, text='Rubrica', font=bold())
r_label.grid(column=0, row=0, columnspan=1, sticky='w')
rubrica_dropdown = ttk.Combobox(frame_rubrica, width=5, state='readonly', values=[R[0] for R in rubric_values])
rubrica_dropdown.grid(column=1, row=0, sticky='w')
label_descRub.grid(column=0, row=1)
label_comRub.grid(column=0, row=2)
descripcion_rubrica.grid(column=1, row=1, sticky='w', columnspan=3)
comentarios_rubrica.grid(column=1, row=2, sticky='w', columnspan=3)
frame_rubrica.grid(column=3, row=0, columnspan=3, rowspan=6, sticky='nw', padx= 10)
rubrica_dropdown.bind('<<ComboboxSelected>>', refresh_rubrica)
# BOTONES

update = tk.Button(entry_frame, text='Actualizar', command=update_puntajes)
update.grid(column=0, row=18, columnspan=3, pady=10, padx=20, sticky='nsew')

# STDIN
stdin_frame = tk.Frame(root)
filename_frame = tk.Frame(stdin_frame)
stdin_labelN = tk.Label(filename_frame, text='Filename: ', font=bold())
stdin_filename = tk.StringVar(filename_frame, 'NONE')
stdin_file = tk.Label(filename_frame, textvariable=stdin_filename)
stdin_label = tk.Label(stdin_frame, text='STD-IN', font=bold(10))
stdin_text = tk.Text(stdin_frame, width=40, height=16)
stdin_scroll = tk.Scrollbar(stdin_frame, command=stdin_text.yview)
runbutton = tk.Button(stdin_frame, text='Run', height=2, command=run)
stdin_text.configure(yscrollcommand=stdin_scroll.set)
stdin_labelN.grid(column=0, row=0, sticky='w')
stdin_file.grid(column=1, row=0, sticky='w')
filename_frame.grid(column=0,row=0, columnspan=2, sticky='w')
stdin_label.grid(column=0, row=3, sticky='w', padx=10)
stdin_text.grid(column=0, row=4, pady=4)
stdin_scroll.grid(column=1, row=4, sticky='nsew')
runbutton.grid(column=0, row=5, sticky='nsew', padx=20, pady=1)
stdin_frame.grid(column=4, row=9, rowspan=16, columnspan=3, padx=10)


#STDOUT
stdout_frame = tk.Frame(root)
stdout_label = tk.Label(stdout_frame, text='STD-OUT', font=bold(10))
stdout_label.grid(column=0, row=0, sticky='w', padx=10)
stdout_var = tk.StringVar(stdout_frame, 'NONE')
stdout_text = tk.Text(stdout_frame, width=40, height=12, state=tk.DISABLED)
stdout_scroll = tk.Scrollbar(stdout_frame, command=stdout_text.yview)
stdout_text.configure(yscrollcommand=stdout_scroll.set)
stdout_text.grid(column=0, row=1)
stdout_scroll.grid(column=1, row=1, sticky='nsew')
stdout_frame.grid(column=9, row=0, rowspan=10, columnspan=3, padx=10)

#STDERR
stderr_frame = tk.Frame(root)
stderr_label = tk.Label(stderr_frame, text='STD-ERR', font=bold(10))
stderr_label.grid(column=0, row=0, sticky='w', padx=10)
stderr_var = tk.StringVar(stderr_frame, 'NONE')
stderr_text = tk.Text(stderr_frame, width=40, height=12, state=tk.DISABLED)
stderr_scroll = tk.Scrollbar(stderr_frame, command=stderr_text.yview)
stderr_text.configure(yscrollcommand=stderr_scroll.set)
stderr_text.grid(column=0, row=1)
stderr_scroll.grid(column=1, row=1, sticky='nsew')
stdin_frame.grid_rowconfigure(1, weight=1)
stdin_frame.grid_columnconfigure(0, weight=1)
stderr_frame.grid(column=9, row=10, rowspan=10, columnspan=3, padx=10)
root.grid_rowconfigure(10, weight=1)
root.grid_columnconfigure(9, weight=1)
root.attributes('-topmost', 'true')
root.geometry('900x600')

#SETUP

config = tk.Tk()
ID_label = tk.Label(config, text='ID Ayudante')
ERROR_VAR = tk.StringVar(config)
ERROR = tk.Label(config, textvariable=ERROR_VAR, fg='red', justify=tk.CENTER)
ID_entry = tk.Entry(config)
ID_button = tk.Button(config, text='Correr', command=process)
ID_label.grid(column=0, row=0, padx=10, pady=10)
ID_entry.grid(column=1, row=0, padx=10, pady=10)
ERROR.grid(column=0, row=2,columnspan=2, sticky='nsew')
ID_button.grid(column=0, row=3, padx=35, columnspan=2, sticky='nsew')
config.grid_rowconfigure(3, weight=1)
config.grid_columnconfigure(0, weight=1)


root.withdraw()
config.geometry('100x100')
config.mainloop()
root.mainloop()
```

Comment: This code won't run as-is. Please make it runnable.

Comment: @BryanOakley Done.

Comment: @NicolasQuiroz this code is still not runnable, you have errors on lines 39 and 52 at least

Comment: All of that other data you added is not necessary. Your original code was good enough, you just needed to remove references to a couple of non-existent functions, and then create the root window. You've added way too much code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your layout is remarkably complex for such a conceptually simple layout. I strongly encourage you to reorganize your code. Tkinter works best when your layouts are simple.

In your case, it appears that your UI has three distinct columns. The first has the section with the heading "Puntaje". The second column has the headings "Rubrica" and "Filename". The third has "STD-OUT" and "STD-ERR". So, my recommendation is to start by creating three frames, one for each section.

For example:

```
left = tk.Frame(root)
middle = tk.Frame(root)
right = tk.Frame(root)
```

You say you only want the text widgets on the right to grow, so you can layout these three columns like this:

```
left.pack(side="left", fill="both", expand=False)
middle.pack(side="left", fill="both", expand=False)
right.pack(side="right", fill="both", expand=True)
```

Do that, and just that. Give each column a distinct color and a temporary width and height so that you can verify they are behaving properly.

Once you have done that, you can focus on each column separately. For example, lets add the stdout and stderr. I'm not sure exactly how you expect them to behave. You say you want them to grow and shrink, but you don't say if they should fill the whole right side or have padding or space between them.

Here's one way to do it. Since you already have a frame, you don't necessarily need additional frames. Just places the text and scrollbars directly in the right column. Though, you can certainly use additional frames if you want. My advice is to either not use extra frames, and use `grid` to lay out the widgets in the right column, or use the extra frames and then use `pack` to simply stack the two widgets and labels on top of each other.

```
# right column, using grid
stdin_label = tk.Label(right, text="STD-IN", anchor="w")
stdin_text = tk.Text(right, width=40, height=16)
stdin_scroll = tk.Scrollbar(right, command=stdin_text.yview, orient="vertical")

stdout_label = tk.Label(right, text="STD-OUT", anchor="w")
stdout_text = tk.Text(right, width=40, height=16)
stdout_scroll = tk.Scrollbar(right, command=stdout_text.yview, orient="vertical")

stdin_label.grid(row=0, column=0, columnspan=2, sticky="nsew")
stdin_text.grid(row=1, column=0, sticky="nsew")
stdin_scroll.grid(row=1, column=1, sticky="ns")

stdout_label.grid(row=2, column=0, columnspan=2, sticky="nsew")
stdout_text.grid(row=3, column=0, sticky="nsew")
stdout_scroll.grid(row=3, column=1, sticky="ns")

right.grid_rowconfigure(1, weight=1)
right.grid_rowconfigure(3, weight=1)
right.grid_columnconfigure(0, weight=1)
```

Do that, and just that, and make sure that the behavior is still correct when you resize the window. Only after you're sure this section is behaving the way you expect should you move on to another column.